# What is the technology of restcomm call transfer?

Tags: architecture, restcomm

I am very interested to learn the technology that works to transfer user call from IVR server to agent PC's.

From my understanding, a client is needed to be installed in agents' PCs. A ringing popup should appear in agents PC to answer.

Please help explaining how calls from IVR server distributed to agents PCs.

thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Restcomm uses Session Initiation Protocol (SIP) - ([RFC 3261](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3261.txt)) which is an application-layer control (signaling) protocol for creating, modifying, and terminating sessions with one or more participants.

That means, if a Client dials to Restcomm, and Restcomm needs to redirect this call to another Client, it will make it using the SIP since the first call until reach the agent PC's. The Client must have a SIP Client software installed in his PC (as you mentioned) or mobile, and should already make the first contact with the server to inform that he is online. This first contact happens over the SIP message "REGISTER", after that, the calls are started by the SIP message "INVITE".

So, learn about SIP is a good start to understand the technologies involved in call flows executed by Restcomm. Here follows some good links about SIP that will probably guide you to a more clear perspective:

1 - http://arstechnica.com/business/2009/12/wired-for-sound-how-sip-won-the-voip-protocol-wars/

2 - http://arstechnica.com/business/2010/01/voip-in-depth-an-introduction-to-the-sip-protocol-part-1/

3 - http://arstechnica.com/tech-policy/2010/03/voip-in-depth-an-introduction-to-the-sip-protocol-part-2/

I hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks for answering. Could I know little more? Assuming SIP client are installed in client machine, when calls are coming in Restcomm IVR server are far more than available agents then how this calls are queued and managed in Restcomm IVR sever?

Comment: You are welcome! Its important to know that Restcomm uses SIP Servlets middleware integrated with his own resources (like RCML applications and Interpreters) which provide different possibilities on how to handle calls and redirect them to different clients, using IVR, conferences, etc. I've suggest you to take a look in this presentation (http://fr.slideshare.net/telestax/restcomm-architecture-design) starting from slide 5, that shows the technology stack involved with Restcomm, followed by another parts of his architecture.

Comment: Thanks for being generous for helping me. I am sorry to bother you. Could you please share some link about Restcomm WebRTC technology? -thanks

Comment: Please, you don't bother me, im glad to help. :) Restcomm WebRTC solution is called Olympus, and it uses a set of JavaScript libraries to perform in a similar way as desktop SIP clients does. You can have more information here (http://docs.telestax.com/how-to-use-olympus-with-restcomm/) and get involved with the project here (https://github.com/Mobicents/olympus). Feel free to bring more questions if you have.

Comment: Thanks ghjansen. Important feedback, Firstly the slide share(fr.slideshare.net/telestax/restcomm-architecture-design) does not depict the queue handling method. Secondly webRTC link (docs.telestax.com/how-to-use-olympus-with-restcomm) is only a user manual. I was trying to understand webRTC technology, mainly if it is possible, how to convert an incoming SIP call to webRTC call to transfer to an agent.

Comment: Hi Rafiqul, I've confirmed with the team and webRTC outgoing calls are disabled for now. So it won't be possible to convert an incoming SIP call to a webRTC call and transfer it to an agent.